# How to remove whitespace from input during Jquery keyup event before displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    <div>
    <tr>
        <td>flat1:<input type="text" name="flat[]" class="flat" value=""/></td>
        <td>price1:<input type="text" name="new_price[]" class="new_price" value=""/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="org_price[]" class="" value=""</td>
    </tr>
</div>
<div>
    <tr>
        <td>flat2:<input type="text" name="flat[]" class="flat" value=""/></td>
        <td>price2:<input type="text" name="new_price[]" class="new_price" value=""/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="org_price[]" class="" value=""</td>

    </tr>
</div>

        <div>
    <tr>
        <td>flat3:<input type="text" name="flat[]" class="flat" value=""/></td>
        <td>price3:<input type="text" name="new_price[]" class="new_price" value=""/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="org_price[]" class="" value=""</td>
    </tr>
</div>
<div>
    <tr>
        <td>flat4:<input type="text" name="flat[]" class="flat" value=""/></td>
        <td>price4:<input type="text" name="new_price[]" class="new_price" value=""/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="org_price[]" class="" value=""</td>

    </tr>
</div>

        <div>
    <tr>
        <td>flat5:<input type="text" name="flat[]" class="flat" value=""/></td>
        <td>price5:<input type="text" name="new_price[]" class="new_price" value=""/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="org_price[]" class="" value=""</td>

    </tr>
</div>

        <div>
    <tr>
        <td>flat6:<input type="text" name="flat[]" class="flat" value=""/></td>
        <td>price6:<input type="text" name="new_price[]" class="new_price" value=""/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="org_price[]" class="" value=""</td>

    </tr>
</div>

        <div>
    <tr>
        <td>flat7:<input type="text" name="flat[]" class="flat" value=""/></td>
        <td>price7:<input type="text" name="new_price[]" class="new_price" value=""/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="org_price[]" class="" value=""</td>

    </tr>
</div>

        <div>
    <tr>
        <td>flat8:<input type="text" name="flat[]" class="flat" value=""/></td>
        <td>price8:<input type="text" name="new_price[]" class="new_price" value=""/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="org_price[]" class="" value=""</td>

    </tr>
</div>

        <div>
    <tr>
        <td>flat9:<input type="text" name="flat[]" class="flat" value=""/></td>
        <td>price9:<input type="text" name="new_price[]" class="new_price" value=""/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="org_price[]" class="" value=""</td>

    </tr>
</div>

        <div>
    <tr>
        <td>flat10:<input type="text" name="flat[]" class="flat" value=""/></td>
        <td>price10:<input type="text" name="new_price[]" class="new_price" value=""/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="org_price[]" class="" value=""</td>

    </tr>
</div>


<p><input type="submit" name="save" value="save"/></p>
```

I want to display what is typed in .flat input box to .new_price input box on keyup Jquery event.  I've accomplished this, but now I want to remove white space from displaying in the .new_price input.  I attempted to use the replace method with no luck.  http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.flat').on('keyup',function(e) {
       $( this ).siblings(".new_price").eq(0).val ( $(this).val() );
    });
});
```

Comment: $.trim('    some string    ');

Comment: I attempted to use $.trim with no luck

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Post edited based on your comments. The way you described it was somewhat misleading.

Just use a string replace in your case.

```
$(this).val().replace(/ /g, "");
```

The `/ /` syntax means a regular expression matching a space and the `g` at the end means global so that it replaces more than just the first occurrence.

Updated jsfiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/112/)

Comment: b1j, That didn't work in the jfiddle, it's still showing the space in the price input

Comment: b1j, It's still allowing spaces in the updated fiddle.  Such as, if you type "this is a test" in Flat1 input the resulting output into the Price1 input is "this is a test" when it should be "thisisatest"

Comment: @user2128903 Ah, seems your question was misunderstood. See updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Add this class 'auto_remove_space' on your element

and on JS add

```
$('.auto_remove_space').on('keyup',function(e) {
  $( this ).val($( this ).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));
});
```